# How can I make my .js File read the HTML variables of my other files and not just one?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a JS file linked to my index.HTML file that works fine but it will not work for other .HTML file. (it won't link to it at all) The elements I need the Javascript to apply to are the same and only have added ID tags on some of them. As I understand it, that should cause no issues as they have the same class name.

Below are the first and second HTML files along with the JS file.

What am I missing here? I thought you could link to the same JS file as long as the HTMLs are the same and have a script tag to link to the JS file. Please help.

Excuse the Jquery mixed with JS. This is pre written code i'm implementing.

Working HTML File:

```
    <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
    <title>Test 1</title>
    </head>
    
    <body>
    
      <!--Navbar-->
      <nav class="navbar">
        <div class="inner-width">
          <a href="/" class="logo"></a>
          <button class="menu-toggle">
              <span></span>
              <span></span>
              <span></span>
            </button>
          <div class="navbar-menu">
            <a href="#home">Home</a>
            <a href="#about">About Us</a>
            <a href="#products">Products</a>
            <a href="#services">Services</a>
            <a href="#training">Training & Support</a>
            <a href="#contact">Contact Us</a>
            <a href="careers.html">Careers </a>
            <div class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropbtn">Log-in</a>
              <div class="dropdown-content">
                <h4>Account Number</h4>
                <form action="#">
                  <input type="text" class="acctNum" placeholder="Account Number" />
                  <h4>Password</h4>
                  <input type="text" class="passWord" placeholder="Password" />
                  <input type="submit" value="Log in" class="login" />
                  <input type="submit" value="Create an Account" class="register" />
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    
      <!--Back to top-->
      <button class="goTop fas fa-arrow-up"></button>
      <script>
        AOS.init();
      </script>
    </body>
```

Not working HTML File:

```
    <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
    
    <title>test file 2</title>
    </head>
    
    <body>
      <!--Navbar-->
      <nav class="navbar">
        <div class="inner-width">
          <a href="/" class="logo"></a>
          <button class="menu-toggle">
                    <span></span>
                    <span></span>
                    <span></span>
                </button>
          <div class="navbar-menu" id="cNavbar-menu">
            <a href="/index.html">Home</a>
            <div class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropbtn">Log-in</a>
              <div class="dropdown-content">
                <h4>Account Name</h4>
                <form action="#">
                  <input type="text" class="acctNum" placeholder="Account Number" />
                  <h4>Password</h4>
                  <input type="text" class="passWord" placeholder="Password" />
                  <input type="submit" value="Log in" class="login" />
                  <input type="submit" value="Create an Account" class="register" />
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    
      <!--Back to top-->
      <button class="goTop fas fa-arrow-up"></button>
      <script>
        AOS.init();
      </script>
    </body>
```

JavaScript:

```
form.addEventListener("submit", handleSubmit)
  $(window).scroll(function () {
    if (this.scrollY > 20) {
      $(".navbar").addClass("sticky");
      $(".goTop").fadeIn();
    } else { 
      $(".navbar").removeClass("sticky");
      $(".goTop").fadeOut();
    }
  });

  $(".goTop").click(function () {
    scroll(0, 0);
  });

  $(".menu-toggle").click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
    $(".navbar-menu").toggleClass("active");
  });
```

This is the error the console produces when trying to run the page. I do not see elements that are different between the two HTML files. Shouldn't the. JS file simply link and then run the functions with the passed over variables?

[image]

Comment: Can you show me the declaration of form.

Comment: `form` appears to be undefined in the JS you've shown. Where do you declare it? Have you omitted something? At a guess maybe it's declared in another JS file or script tag which is included in the first HTML file, but not the second?

Comment: Please check this link you need to define form variable
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit_event